# What "this is not a function; it cannot be applied" error means?

Tags: ocaml

I'm quite new to OCaml and I'm having this error :

```
 let n = read_int ()
    let rec pi  = 
  match n with
  | _ when n < 0 || n > 10000 -> raise (Failure "pi")
  | 1 -> 2. *. ((2. *. 2.) /. (1. *. 3.))
  | _ -> float_of_int (n * n * 2 * 2) /. float_of_int ((2 * n - 1) * (2 * n + 1)) *. pi (n - 1)
```

```
This expression has type float
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

This code works without the `read_int ()` but I need `read_int` in this case .

Comment: The code you've posted does not produce the error you claim it does.

Comment: Im using ocamlopt compiler and i tested right now and I'm having an error wow

Answer (score 1):

Without an argument there

```
 let rec pi =
```

you are not defining a recursive function, but a recursive value `pi` (which happens to be a float). Thus the compiler is raising an error when you are trying to use this float `pi` as a function

```
6 |   | _ -> float_of_int (n * n * 2 * 2) /. float_of_int ((2 * n - 1) * (2 * n + 1)) *. pi (n - 1)
                                                                                         ^^
Error: This expression has type float
       This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

You need to first define `pi` as a function. And once this function is defined, you will be able to call it on your input value.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your code, you can see that :

```ml
 let n = read_int ()
    let rec pi  = 
      match n with
      | _ when n < 0 || n > 10000 -> raise (Failure "pi")
      | 1 -> 2. *. ((2. *. 2.) /. (1. *. 3.))
      | _ -> float_of_int (n * n * 2 * 2) /. float_of_int ((2 * n - 1) * (2 * n + 1)) *. pi   (n - 1)
```

`pi` is not a function, it is a value. Since `pi` does not take any argument. A probably workaround is to gives "n" as a parameter:

```ml
let rec pi n = 
  match n with
  | _ when n < 0 || n > 10000 -> raise (Failure "pi")
  | 1 -> 2. *. ((2. *. 2.) /. (1. *. 3.))
  | _ -> float_of_int (n * n * 2 * 2) /. float_of_int ((2 * n - 1) * (2 * n + 1)) *. pi   (n - 1)
```

Comment: I understood, so if i use read_int i can give n as a parameter and its ok?

Comment: I think you have to separate the concerns. `read_int ()` gives you a (potential) integer, and pi compute something. So you can separate the computation (`pi`) and the reading of the int.

Comment: Okok thanks, but to see if it works out how can I print the returned value of pi? (I'm very new, only  used c in the past)

Comment: Since your function `pi` returns a `float` you defintely can print it ;) you can have, `let x = pi value_for_n` and after printing x.

Comment: Thanks :), btw how do i tranform a exception to  a print ?

Comment: Exception mut be captured using "try/with".

Comment: I want to replace that raise(Failure "Pi")   with a printed string but I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Your function returns a float so you can't print directly in the function. So a solution will be to capture the exception outside of the function. For example : `try let result = pi your_number in Printf.printf "%f" result with Failure message -> print_string message`